# How to switch (migrate) to Google Cloud SQL from DataStore?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-sql

I have a Google App Engine Java application, which uses Appengine datastore for its persistence (Using JPA and Datanucleus).
Now I want to migrate my backend(database) to Google Cloud SQL.
I have already created cloud sql account and instance. I also granted permission for my GAE app to use this instance.

Now, how I can i rewrite my app or what are the changes I should make to my application, in order to migrate to cloud sql.

Any good tutorial is there for it? 
Any help is greatly welcomed.

Comment: I don't have a link for you, migration is usually done the other way around. Why are you moving to SQL? Can you share some of your code?

Comment: Actually I am developing an app for a competition where the requirement is to use Cloud SQL as backend.
my app is built and works perfectly with google datastore using JPA and Datanucleus as persistence provider.
What change I have to make it to work with cloud sql. I have configured cloud sql instance in AppEngine settings of my eclipse project.
@DanHolevoet
which part of my code should I share with u? persistence.xml or any DAO class methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest following [Using Google Cloud SQL with App Engine Java SDK](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/developers-guide). Once you've configured an example database, create new tables for the entities in your datastore.

For the actual data migration you have a few possible routes:

- [Download your datastore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata) locally, manipulate the entries into SQL `INSERT` statements, and upload them to Cloud SQL
- Write a script that reads through the datastore and writes rows to your SQL datastore (most likely using a task queue and datastore cursor)
- Ignore the old data in your app and start from scratch

Comment: Thank you @Dan.
I have already modified my app to work with Hibernate and cloud sql.

But the problem is that, if I choose local mysql server to run the app(during development), it is throwing an exception `code`java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission modifyThreadGroup)`code` , but the app works fine once set to use the cloud sql instance. How can I resolve it?